# C++: vector<Foo*> with reserve(), push_back() destroying values

Tags: c++, vector

The title is a tad confusing. Here is a greatly compressed version of my current predicament:

Classes.h:

```
class Foo {
    int x;
    Foo(): x(0) { }
    Foo(int y): x(y) { }
};

class B {
    vector<Foo> list;
    B() { }
};

class A {
    vector<B> map;
    A() { }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
vector<A> map;
vector<Foo*> allFoos;

void initialize() {
    allFoos.reserve(...);
}

void generateMap() {
    for (...) {
        A a;
        map.push_back(a);
        for (...) {
            B b;
            map.back().map.push_back(b);
            if (...) {
                switch (...) {
                case ...:
                    Foo foo(5);
                    map.back().map.back().list.push_back(foo);
                    allFoos.push_back(&map.back().map.back().list.back());
                    cout << allFoos.back()->x; // #1
                    break;
                }
                cout << allFoos.back()->x; // #2
            }
            cout << allFoos.back()->x; // #3
        }
        cout << allFoos.back()->x; // #4
    }
    cout << allFoos.back()->x; // #5
}

int main() {
    initialize();
    generateMap();
}
```

When I run my code, I am perfectly able to retrieve `allFoos.back()`; I can access the members via `->`, and upon using a Break, with MVC++ Express 2013, I can hover over `allFoos` and be given a list of all of its elements...problem is, any elements but the `back()` element are **complete nonsense**.

Sporadically, the member values become nonsensical; <strike>at #1, #2, #4, and #5, it will print '5'. At #3, it will print a gibberish number +- a few million.</strike>*

After a multitude of Breaks, dumping of variables, etc., I have determined that the problem is that `push_back(...)` is somehow altering the location of the preceding pointers, despite `reserve(...)` allocating far more than enough space to hold as many `Foo*`s as I need.

I am absolutely lost. I have tried for hours to understand why this is happening, but to no avail. I have looked at literally hundreds of similar questions, but none close enough to help out my issue (unless I have just been insufficient in applying their solutions to my own problem.)

If more information is necessary, it can be provided.

**Update:**

<strike>Here's what's stranger: if I create a `printDetails()` member function inside of the `Foo` class and use that for `allFoos.back()` at #5 instead, all of the `Foo`'s member values print **perfectly fine** - and the same hover-over technique reveals that the last `Foo*` is the only one with details intact.</strike>*

**Update #2:**

*I have found that everything I said changes depending on the run - each time, different locations print different values, and I have been unable to pin down a location that provides consistent results. It seems as though I have hit *undefined behavior* somewhere, but I can't seem to find where...

Comment: Are you sure that the scope of the variables is the same in your example and in your real code? Your description really sounds like your `map` variable gets destructed before you iterate over `allFoos`, which would render all your pointers values pointing to invalid data.

Comment: I am entirely sure - `vector<A> map;` is defined along with a surplus of other values at the beginning of `main.cpp`. All of `vector<Foo*> allFoos`'s Foo's should still be pointing to their correct locations...I am unsure as to why they stop operating randomly and later become useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointers are invalidated, because when you are pushing values in the vectors, some will eventually get expanded. Because a vector stores data contiguously, when reallocating, existing values are moved to another place in memory. Thus, your raw pointers points to previous, invalid locations.

If you want to continue populating your vectors as in your example, you should reserve proper size for all vectors beforehand. But keep in mind that keeping raw pointers to vector elements will eventually bring up the same probleme again.

Comment: This is why I included `reserve(...)` in the beginning, to prevent reallocation. It is larger than the number of `Foo*`s put into it. **Update:** wait...I think I understand now. Let me see if I can reserve space for the other maps beforehand...

Comment: @CarsonWilber you are reserving space for the vector containing raw pointers, not the other vectors (in `A` and `B`)

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I see it all now. Is there any way I can fix this? Or is it just better to create a function that runs through the map at the end and creates the pointers?

Comment: @CarsonWilber It depends on what is the purpose of `allFoos`; why do you want to store pointers to your instances? You already have access to them in your `map`.

Comment: Currently, for development purposes, but in other applications I wish to allow the player to keep track of previously encountered objects and be able to look up information about them easily. ...Perhaps a little background information would help: I am making a text-based space adventure game. Static objects, such as planets and stars, would not be as tricky; dynamic objects, such as ships and crewmembers, may be more difficult, as they constantly change location. I believe I am going to change it so that crew/ships point to location, and location points to crew/ships...

Comment: @CarsonWilber Without changing the whole design, you could use another type of container than vectors in `A` and `B`, that do not store data contiguously, but choosing the appropriate one will depend on the operations you will perform on it; eg. a `list` will preserve the order of insertion but is slow to find an element, while a `set` is efficient for searching but items are unique and const, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for all the help piwi! I've been messing around and I think I've found a system that works: I store the locations of each planet/star/ship as integers inside their objects, and the IDs of the planets/stars/ships in each location in integers/integer vectors in the locations' objects. Basically, a two-way referencing system devoid of pointers. Works much more smoothly than *with*!